# Sphinx - How to index only a limited number of words?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I have limited number of industries (around 300 industries), I would like to create an index which will give the frequency of these keywords in the indexed documents. Is there any way for doing this in sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

But the --buildstops function of indexer, will produce a list of the most common keywords in an index.

So can just look at the output of that, and compare with your industry list. In theory I would think your industries should near the top of the list, so dont have to make it too long.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick in Sphinx to get keyword statistics from the index. BuildKeywords API call ( http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildkeywords ) with *hits* flag set will return per keyword frequencies from given index.

Hope this helps